# Microsoft Account: can't log in

Tags: macos, microsoft-office

I bought Microsoft Office on my PC a few months ago and I entered the product key on the Office page to download Office on my Mac laptop as well. I was logged in and everything but it downloaded an executable file (`.exe`). So i searched a little bit and got a link to the site where you apparently can download Office for mac ([this site right here](http://portal.office.com/OLS/MySoftware.aspx)). I don't know if it is a scam, however, when I tried to log in, it gave me an error:

```
(my email address) ist nicht in unserem System enthalten. 
Stellen Sie sicher, dass Sie den Namen richtig eingegeben haben.
```

It's German and it basically means that the email address isn't in the system of Microsoft. On the second line it says "Please make sure you have entered the address correctly."
Everywhere I looked it says, Microsoft is doing some stuff (maintenance or something like that) on their servers but it doesn't work for like days...

Thank you for eventual help!

Comment: The portal URL is legitimate. Where did you make your original purchase?

Comment: Sadly this might be something only MS customer support can resolve. Are you able to login on other Microsoft sites?

Comment: @Tetsujin I did it on https://mmoga.com but it worked fine, also, I could activate the Product Key I received without problems.

Comment: @Burgi Yes, when i go to https://login.microsoft.com I can log in without problems

Comment: I've never heard of mmoga, so I've no clue if it's legitimate or not. I'd suspect you didn't actually sign up with MS as part of your registration. BTW, unless you got Office 365, your license for 'regular' office is for only one computer. You'd have to speak to MS about transferring it.

Comment: @Tetsujin The thing is: my PC broke recently with Office installed; I repaired it by reinstalling Windows. When I visited https://www.office.com logged in, entered my old Product Key, I managed to download Office again. What I actually want to do is install Office on my MacBook. Do you maybe know how to do it? It would really help me out. And also, when I logged in at www.office.com, it actually downloaded when I entered the old Product Key in my MacBook. However, it was a `.exe` file

Comment: I still think you'll have to speak to MS - your license isn't transferrable manually without the old install to de-register from first.